# Can I amplify a voltage with with a gain around 100 using an op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I need to amplify a voltage that ranges from 0.049 to 0.059 V to a value of 2 to 5 V. Can this be done using an op-amp?

[image]

I used this circuit for the design, but while designing I got a negative value for R3. It is because the gain is very high.

Is there any way to do this?

I got the design method from [this TI design document](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa262a/sboa262a.pdf).

Comment: So you want \$y=300\cdot x-12.7\$?

Comment: Yes. You can do it. Gain is around 300. Will answer later. I am on road.

Comment: What supply voltage can you provide? 5V? 12V? 18V?

Comment: Current used 5V. But I can increase the supply voltage if I can use another opamp?

Answer (score 4):

The gain is more like (as in exactly) 300 than  100. With such a large gain the +/-1.5mV input offset voltage of this particular model of op-amp means you'll have an offset at the output of as much as +/-450mV depending on which sample of op-amp you happen to have. So you either must use an op-amp with a lower Vos (such as a zero-drift type) or add an adjustment. Gain, on the other hand, is going to be mostly dependent on resistor tolerances provided the op-amp gain is sufficiently high compared to 300.

There's **no** reason to attenuate the input voltage, it's already really low and you will unnecessarily have a **low input impedance**. You do need to have another resistor to get this to work with a (more desirable) positive reference voltage. Also, you won't get all the way to 5V on the output, even with a so-called rail-to-rail output, but you'll get 'closer' than you would without such a component. You can always add a resistor (eg. 1MΩ or whatever you would like it to be) to ground from the non-inverting input if you want to avoid it floating when disconnected.

Here is the general idea, but keep in mind the Vos of the op-amp means the behavior shown is quite unlikely to be what you see if you build the circuit. I've also increased the supply voltage to 6V (absolute maximum) just to avoid it saturating at <5V on the output. You would not do that in practice, you'd more likely choose something like 2V to 4.5V on the output.

[image]

Because you are offsetting by ~5x the total range, the output is going to be very sensitive to resistor R3 and reference tolerance (and drift).

Answer (score 2):

As **example**, here is the schematic I use (NB: one power supply offset is "negative".

[image]

Or **this one**.

[image]

Note that just 5V ... can't be, very near it can be.

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants to amplify [0.049, 0.059] range to [2, 5] range i.e. the output should be 2V for 49mV input.

Comment: Just choose the "correct" R5. It is very "sensitive" ... And R1.

Comment: Can you confirm what will be V3.
V4 is my input signal
V8 is the reference voltage.
Is v3 is ground?

Comment: All yes. V3 is 0 -> ground (Was used in another simulation). V8 can also be VC.